# Nuxt 3, how add dynamically routes after nuxt started from API?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm trying add new routes of components after nuxt started, but I don't find solution. My aproach is:

```
export default <RouterConfig> {

    routes: (_routes) => {

        const response = axios('http://localhost:8090/pull-connectivity/information/website/100000/routes');

        response.then((res) => {

            // Routes from the API, how to add them to the routes?
            console.log(res.data.result);

        });

    const local = [
                {
                    name: 'home',
                    path: '/',
                    component: () => import('~/pages/home.vue').then(r => r.default || r)
                },
                {
                    name: 'test',
                    path: '/test',
                    component: () => import('~/pages/test.vue').then(r => r.default || r)
                },
                // how add this after started?
                //...res.data.result
            ];

     return local;
     },
}
```

The fetch run well, but it is async promise. I can't add routes at started I'll need do it later, and refresh for new routes every minute
Any suggestion?
Regads